# Dark mode TypeError: Cannot set property 'onClick' of null

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

this is my code trying to add the theme button that toggles the color of the website so I used the CSS variables and i did know what is the problem with the js code

```js
const darkButton = document.getElementById('dark');
const lightButton = document.getElementById('light');
const body = document.body;
darkButton.onClick = () => {
  body.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
};

lightButton.onClick = () => {
  body.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
};
```

```css
.light {
  --bg: var(--gray0);
  --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray1), var(--gray3));
  --bg-dropdown: var(--gray0);
  --text: var(--gray6);
  --border-color: var(--blue);
  --bg-solar: var(--yellow);
}


.dark {
  --bg: var(--gray5);
  --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray5), var(--gray6));
  --bg-dropdown: var(--gray6);
  --text: var(--gray0);
  --border-color: var(--purple);
  --bg-solar: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<div>
            <div class="nav-item has-dropdown">
              <button className="nav-link Togglebutton" href="/">
                Theme
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-item column">
                  <div id="light">light</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-item column">
                  <div id="dark">dark</div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

thin I have this error

Comment: Are you using jquery?

Comment: try this and let me know ```window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {   //put your code here})```  because your code is working on my machine

Answer (score 0):

Replace your javascript with

```
const darkButton = document.getElementById('dark');
const lightButton = document.getElementById('light');
const body = document.body;
lightButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
});
darkButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
  body.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
  localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
});
```

Comment: it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: Please explain to OP *why* he should this and why his first attempt didn't work.

Comment: i tryed [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXuHGLzSmSE&feature=youtu.be&fbclid=IwAR2ezBny3Dbl2etO0hqqbKJtzjCsUJzNPhbX3R-Kj5fpIajSeUcWs97VTzU)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `onclick` instead of `onClick`

```js
const darkButton = document.getElementById('dark');
const lightButton = document.getElementById('light');
const body = document.body;
body.classList.add('light')
darkButton.onclick = () => {
  body.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
  //commented as it wont work on so snippet
  //localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
  console.log("Im dark button");
};

lightButton.onclick = () => {
  body.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
  //commented as it wont work on so snippet
  //localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
   console.log("Im light button");
};
```

```css
.light {
  --bg: var(--gray0);
  --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray1), var(--gray3));
  --bg-dropdown: var(--gray0);
  --text: var(--gray6);
  --border-color: var(--blue);
  --bg-solar: var(--yellow);
}


.dark {
  --bg: var(--gray5);
  --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray5), var(--gray6));
  --bg-dropdown: var(--gray6);
  --text: var(--gray0);
  --border-color: var(--purple);
  --bg-solar: var(--blue);
}
```

```html
<div>
            <div class="nav-item has-dropdown">
              <button className="nav-link Togglebutton" href="/">
                Theme
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-item column">
                  <div id="light">light</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-item column">
                  <div id="dark">dark</div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I did that nothing changed

Comment: as you can see its working in the snippet.I think your javascript is running before dom is available? Try adding this code after document is ready

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```html
<html>

<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function toggle(i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                document.body.classList.replace('light', 'dark');
                localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
            }
            if (i == 1) {
                document.body.classList.replace('dark', 'light');
                localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <div class="nav-item has-dropdown">
            <button className="nav-link Togglebutton" href="/">
                Theme
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-item column">
                    <div id="light" onclick="toggle(0)">light</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-item column">
                    <div id="dark" onclick="toggle(1)">dark</div>
                </div>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope, this code might help you.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      theme: ""
    }
  }

darkButton = () => {
  this.setState({
    theme:"dark"
  });
  window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark');
};

lightButton = () => {
  this.setState({
    theme:"light"
  });
  window.localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light');
};
  
  
  render() {
    return (
    <div className={this.state.theme}>
            <div class="nav-item has-dropdown">
              <button className="nav-link Togglebutton" href="/">
                Theme
              </button>
              <ul class="dropdown">
                <div class="dropdown-item column"  onClick={this.lightButton}>
                  <div id="light">light</div>
                </div>
                <div class="dropdown-item column" onClick={this.darkButton}>
                  <div id="dark">dark</div>
                </div>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, window.root);
```

```css
.light {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.dark {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```